# Getting the value of a regex group in a replace call

Tags: regex, replace, clojure

I have a vector `s` and string `x`:

```
(def s [5 6 7])
(def x "echo %1 %2 %3")
```

I would like to convert `%n` in `x` to value `s[n-1]` to produce:

```
echo 5 6 7
```

How would I do this? The furthest I've got so far is:

```
(clojure.string/replace code #"%(\d)" (s "$1"-1))
```

But that obviously does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A replacement parameter of the `clojure.string/replace` function can be either a string or a function that takes a match of the pattern and returns a string. In this case, it should be a function as follows.

```
user> (def s [5 6 7])
#'user/s

user> (def x "echo %1 %2 %3")
#'user/x

user> (defn replacement [match] (-> match second Long/parseLong dec s str))
#'user/replacement

user> (clojure.string/replace x #"%(\d)" replacement)
"echo 5 6 7"
```

The `replacement` function takes a vector of two strings, because each match is given as a vector of string.

```
user> (re-seq #"%(\d)" "echo %1 %2 %3")
(["%1" "1"] ["%2" "2"] ["%3" "3"])
```